# How to mock $nuxt object in vue-test-utils and jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I am using vue-test-utils and jest in order to test my code.
My test run without any problem except if it pass through the code below

```
$nuxt.$store.commit("device/saveState", {
      id: this.$.id,
      key: this.$.ac_key,
      power: this.$.ac_power,
      mode: this.$.ac_mode,
      temp: this.$.ac_temp,
      wind: this.$.ac_wind
    })
```

and it will give me this error

```
 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: $nuxt is not defined"
```

Comment: did you tried `this.$nuxt...`?

Comment: I am using vue-mc, the code above is for vue-mc and I can only access "this" by using "$nuxt".

Comment: I'm sorry if its confusing but in vue-mc $nuxt is the equivalent of this.

Comment: @4thyearstupident I'm having the same problem. Did you happen to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In `jest.config.js`:

```js
    module.exports = {
      setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/tests/setup.js'],
    }
```

Then in `tests/setup.js`:

```js
    global.$nuxt = { 
      refresh: () => {}
    }
```

Finally, in your tests file:

```js
    const mock: any = jest.fn()
    window.$nuxt.refresh = mock
    
    const wrapper = mount(Component, {
      localVue
    })

    const button = wrapper.find('.refresh-button')
    await button.trigger('click')

    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Because it's a global, remember to tear down your mock or reassign it to something else in an afterEach() block.